# Android geocoder reverse location - reliable way to get the city?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-geocoder

I have searched quite a bit without luck so far.

The Android Geocoder returns the `android.location.Address` object.
The city, as far as I understood, should be returned in `getLocality()`.
It seems within USA this works well, outside not.

I am writing an international app and struggle to find a solution to find out the city of a geolocation.

Here the output from Czech Republic/Prague :

```
Address[addressLines=
[0:"Psohlavců 1764/2",
1:"147 00 Prague-Prague 4",
2:"Czech Republic"],
feature=2,
admin=Hlavní město Praha,
sub-admin=Prague,
locality=null,
thoroughfare=Psohlavců,
postalCode=147 00,
countryCode=CZ,
countryName=Czech Republic,
hasLatitude=true,
latitude=50.0276543,
hasLongitude=true,
longitude=14.4183926,
phone=null,
url=null,
extras=null]
```

`locality` is null, the city is within `sub-admin` !
The address itself is ok, so the geocoder server seems to know the city.

Here some ore random EU examples but locality works partly:

```
Address[addressLines=[0:"Nad lesem 440/34",1:"147 00 Prague-Prague 4",2:"Czech Republic"],feature=34,admin=Hlavní město Praha,sub-admin=Prague,locality=null,thoroughfare=Nad lesem,postalCode=147 00,countryCode=CZ,countryName=Czech Republic,hasLatitude=true,latitude=50.02424,hasLongitude=true,longitude=14.4117568,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]

Address[addressLines=[0:"Hauner Straße 4",1:"84431 Heldenstein",2:"Germany"],feature=4,admin=null,sub-admin=null,locality=Heldenstein,thoroughfare=Hauner Straße,postalCode=84431,countryCode=DE,countryName=Germany,hasLatitude=true,latitude=48.2540274,hasLongitude=true,longitude=12.3413535,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]

Address[addressLines=[0:"Igler Straße",1:"6020 Innsbruck",2:"Austria"],feature=Igler Straße,admin=Tyrol,sub-admin=Innsbruck,locality=Innsbruck,thoroughfare=Igler Straße,postalCode=6020,countryCode=AT,countryName=Austria,hasLatitude=true,latitude=47.2465698,hasLongitude=true,longitude=11.4054237,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]

Address[addressLines=[0:"Durnberg 24",1:"5724 Stuhlfelden",2:"Austria"],feature=24,admin=Salzburg,sub-admin=Zell am See District,locality=null,thoroughfare=Durnberg,postalCode=5724,countryCode=AT,countryName=Austria,hasLatitude=true,latitude=47.3233373,hasLongitude=true,longitude=12.4960482,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]

Address[addressLines=[0:"U Roháčových kasáren 14",1:"100 00 Prague 10",2:"Czech Republic"],feature=14,admin=Hlavní město Praha,sub-admin=Prague,locality=Prague 10,thoroughfare=U Roháčových kasáren,postalCode=null,countryCode=CZ,countryName=Czech Republic,hasLatitude=true,latitude=50.0704092,hasLongitude=true,longitude=14.4673473,phone=null,url=null,extras=null]
```

Maybe the fault is on me, but to me it seems like depending on the country and area the city will be found in different fields.
However, the address itself mostly seems to be good enough to send a postal letter.

Has someone written a clever function which tries to make more sense out of the Geocoder results ? It's a pity to see that Google has the information stored but does not provide it properly.

Comment: Yup. It different in some countries. Look at locality first, if that is empty, check sub-admin.

Comment: Are you sure sub-admin is reliable as alternative if locality is empty ?

Comment: Just based on my experience, it's either in locality or sub-admin. Haven't encountered a scenario where both are empty.

Comment: This is a bug. Even i experienced the same issue. Unfortunately i haven't found a workaround to it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Going to close my question, solved it with a workaround.
Using the suggestion from dannyroa

```
String city="unknown";
if (address.getLocality() != null)  city=address.getLocality();
else
  if (address.getSubAdminArea() != null)  city=address.getSubAdminArea();
```

This could be further extended by getting the city information out of the second address line.
removing the postal code and taking the remainder, but this information is not unique within a city and could change depending on the district/zone.

Comment: It's not reliable too as sometimes getSubAdminArea() also returns null, but city stays in mAdminArea (and in strange format "city CityName"). Seems this reverse geocoding is not enough reliable

Comment: Maybe you can supply an example location ?
Google has done hell of a bad job with it, they probably started and realized how bad their data is fitting into new countries. 
It looks like they kept extending their already misfitting structures with more and more data, shoveling it here and there.

However: You CAN make it reliable. If this code fails in a particular country then you just need to find the "right rules" for that country and add an "if" case to it.
So far it worked on all countries relevant to me (so far)

Comment: Not reliable at all. sub admin area is not always the city.

Comment: The same counts for you as for Leo. Without an example your comment is useless.